How to install local utilities like poppler-utils in streamlit application?
I have a streamlit application which uses pdf2Image, which requires that you install poppler-utils linux package: https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image
I installed it locally to make it work. But if I want to deploy it on streamlit cloud, I need to be able to specify somehow that you need to install poppler utils.
If I don't post deployment it says throws an error that poppler was not found on your device, have you installed it?
How can I do this ?
I want to use the subprocess module, however it will prompt me for a password, which I won't be able to interact with.
